# Where should I place java and test folders in webapp maven project?

Tags: web-applications, maven-2, directory

There is an archetype for webapp:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.company \
                       -DartifactId=my-webapp \
                       -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
                       -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

This will generate the following structure:

```
$ tree my-webapp/
my-webapp/
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── resources
        └── webapp
            ├── index.jsp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── web.xml
```

Where should I place Java sources (and tests)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply place your source as usual within my-webapp/src/main/java and your tests within my-webapp/src/test/java.

Maven will create your webapp inside of my-webapp/target